# Distance of $x$ to kernel of bounded linear functional is the norm of the functional at $x$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $f\in X^*$ have norm $1$. Prove that $x\in X\implies d(x,\text{ker} f)=|f(x)|$.

I have managed to prove that $d(x,\text{ker}f) \geq |f(x)|$, using a theorem that $d(z,Y)=\max_{l\in Y^\perp,||l||\leq1} |l(z)|$. But I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. I can't see how the space being Banach is relevant.

I know that the kernel of $f$ will be closed, but I also can't see how to make hay out of that.

Comment: Can you show that for any $x\in X$ there exists $y\in\ker f$ such that $|f(x-y)|=\|x-y\|$?

Comment: I can see how that would help (since $f$ is linear, it would all but complete the proof), but not how to achieve it. I'll keep thinking about that, but can you offer any hints about why this should be easier than directly showing the same thing for $x$ rather than $x-y$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the definition of norm, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a unit vector $u$ such that $f(u)>1-\epsilon$. Given $x$ with $f(x)\ne 0$, let 
$$
y = x-\frac{f(x)}{f(u)} u
$$
By construction, $f(y) = 0 $, meaning $y\in \ker y$. Hence, 
$$
\operatorname{dist}(x,\ker f )\le \|x-y\| = \frac{|f(x)|}{|f(u)|}<\frac{|f(x)|}{1-\epsilon}
$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $\operatorname{dist}(x,\ker f )\le  |f(x)|$.

---

For completeness: the reverse inequality follows from the fact that for every $y\in \ker f$,
$$
\|x-y\|\ge |f(x-y)|=|f(x)|
$$

---

The space being complete is not relevant here. Many of the simpler results about Banach spaces do not use completeness, but are stated in this setting anyway.